# Add [privileges] to magic comment links

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, magic-links

I have been viewing a lot of first posts from new users. I often see answers such as "thanks", or "me too", or they are asking a different question altogether. I like to point out the fact that they will eventually be able to comment their opinions and upvote answers that they like. So I would like to have a comment such as

> Hello user, and welcome to [main]. It is great that the answer helped you, however, that is not the purpose of adding an answer. Soon enough, with just a little bit of work, you will gain [help/privileges/comment] and be able to comment and upvote answers that help you.

`[privileges]` would link to the site's privilege page, and `/comment` would link to the page in privileges that talks about commenting. <s>Hash tags could be used to indicate any section of the privileges page.</s> [As hammar pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181063/add-privileges-to-magic-comment-links#comment554258_181063), because each privilege is a different page, the magic links would have to be slashes. For example

- [[help/privileges/comment]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - Comment page
- [[help/privileges/established]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) - Established user
- [[help/privileges/protect]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) - Protect Questions

This would work similar to the FAQ magic link comments

Comment: Hello user, and welcome to [metase]. It is great that the answer helped you, however, that is not the purpose of adding an answer. Soon enough, with just a little bit of work, you will gain [privileges] and be able to comment and upvote answers that help you.

Comment: I think you do not know about this: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: No I do. It's my favorite stack overflow plugin

Comment: Since those are actually different pages, and not just different anchors on the same page (like the `[faq]` ones), they shouldn't be using `#`. I'd prefer `[privileges/comment]`, etc.