# New design for the privileges page on meta. Open for feedback

Tags: discussion, privileges, feedback

**The changes have now been rolled out across the network!**

---

Most of these changes are cosmetic.

We moved the list into the main content area, increased the font size a little, and used the check marks from badges to show progression.

Each privilege gets a one sentence summary so that you can easily browse the list, and we have added categories and filters to help you get a better idea of what kind of privileges there are.

Finally, we have added a progress bar to the right sidebar instead of showing simultaneous progression for all of the privileges.

[new privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: I like it.. but what is "our new feature process"? Is it "Our *new* feature process" or "our *new feature process*"?

Comment: Love it.... but it is just so disappointing to see how close to the top I am (in terms of number of privileges left to earn), but yet I am  no where close to getting there.  The old way was so much less ... disappointing :-)

Comment: A+, would surprisingly find nothing to complain about again

Comment: @Seth Where do you see that?

Comment: @JeremyTunnell It's in the blurb about moderation in the sidebar

Comment: Wow this is awesome! I love it

Comment: My response is _Oh I like it!_  Actually I love it.

Comment: I liked the simultaneous percentage counters. Maybe you could add them to the checkmark column for unachieved things.

Comment: @Toomai I just didn't think it made sense for something that happens as a progression. And we found from user testing that newer users couldn't understand what the percentages meant or why they were all different

Comment: Where's the diamond privilege!?!?!  For everyone but mods it should say "U CAN NOT HAS CHEEZBURGER".

Comment: I like it, but next step could be renaming [Reputation & Privileges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) to just Reputation.

Comment: Changes are live, so I have edited. Feel free to change/alter the message I added.

Comment: Love the new design. Quite like the way you can see all "rewards" on one page.

Answer (score 30):

**Update: this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), yay!**

---

[image]

This is misleading - it seems like I'm only about 10% of the way there when in reality I'm more that halfway there.

Could the bar start from 0 instead of starting from the amount of rep needed for the previous privilege?

Comment: The page looks great overall, but I'm with you. I have _no idea_ what that bar is supposed to represent. My filled-in bit is about twice as long: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RPkdc.png, and I have a little less than twice as much rep, so that seems to be absolute reputation, but what determined the length of the bar as a whole? Jeff Atwood's rep? Is his bar full?

Comment: @JoshCaswell The start of the bar is the last privilege you gained, and the end point is the next privilege. (wait never mind, after examining your comment more I have no idea what the bar is supposed to be :P)

Comment: The zero of the bar was the rep required for your last gained privilege (5k). Anyways, the zero is now... zero (pending deploy).

Comment: I linked the wrong picture in my comment above. This is it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pusRM.png So Doorknob's green bar is the 494 rep e has out of the 5000 between 5000 and 10k. I see where that came from now. It's mostly confusing when combined with the text below. I assumed that they were redundant, @Sklivvz; I don't find it at all intuitive that they represent two different measurements.

Answer (score 13):

Please also mention the reputation requirement for the privilege in its page, and not just in the summary pages.

I often link directly to the privilege page (mostly to the "comment everywhere" one) in comments, and in the new design there's no way of knowing how much reputation is necessary to earn the privilege (if you land directly on the privilege page).

Comment: Maybe with an "Awarded at: 150 reputation" or something next to the name or privilege type?

Comment: good point. will fix that.

Comment: This is done (pending deploy).

Answer (score 10):

**Update: Fixed**

I see a Facebook logo next to the name of each privilege. It looks like it's supposed to be a key to the privilege type, but they're all the same.

[image]

Comment: Did you try a hard refresh? The Facebook logo is in that sprite, so my guess is you somehow don't have the latest CSS.

Comment: That's actually pretty funny. I thought for a minute that you were trying to say that all of the icons look like Facebook logos.

Comment: @TimStone I tried clearing my browser cache and it still looks the same as above.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Ah, someone didn't know Firefox has no idea what `background-position-x` is, it seems (Chrome apparently does, which is why I couldn't repro at first)

Comment: I see it, too. (For what it's worth.)

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, I was just about to update that this only happens in Firefox. Looks good in IE.

Comment: Yeah, I see this in Firefox but not Chrome.

Comment: I see this in Firefox as well.

Comment: yeah it's due to background-position-x(y) not supported by Firefox. I pushed a fix for it, it will be live after the next production build.

Comment: Thanks @Jin. It's working now.

Comment: @Jin you actually *fixed Firefox* !!!!1!

Answer (score 2):

The links don't work if you have JavaScript disabled. I know JavaScript is recommended for Stack Exchange, but come on, they're just links.

Comment: Uh oh... [Complaintlessness rescended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186345/new-design-for-the-privileges-page-on-meta-open-for-feedback/186398#comment571635_186345)!

Comment: Well, technically they *aren't* any links in there. They're all just divisions with hover effects and a hand cursor, and JavaScript detects the click and redirects you. But it does seem odd they chose that path for them...

Answer (score 1):

#### Feature Request

I would like to be able to see how much rep I have to gain before I gain each individual privilege. The main page shows how close you are to achieving the next privilege, and each privilege's page shows how close you are to that privilege. However, I miss not being able to see how far I am from each privilege without having to go to one of the individual privilege pages. In the past, this has been implicated as a tooltip.

#### Feature Request

I posted a feature request relating to privileges, so I will link it here for consistency

[Add [privileges] to magic comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181063/add-privileges-to-magic-comment-links)