# New Privileges page with facebook kind of logo

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Is this by-design or some mistake? I see a Facebook icon on the [new privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). It is really not looking great if it is the new design.

[image]

Comment: That'd be a mistake somewhere, but I don't see that.

Comment: Closing as a dupe of the just-posted announcement, because the same problem has been reported there.

Comment: where? I do not see any post with this issue.

Comment: I see that in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: [Bill the Lizard posted it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186346/140890) there.

Comment: Try a forced refresh; the CSS sprites have been updated.