# Bug: Help Center Privileges Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center

I just noticed the new Help Center's "Privileges" page.  I really like what has been done, except for one thing...  all the icons are the Facebook/G+/other sharing site icons.

[image: Bug Screenshot]

In fact, right-clicking on the icon and selecting "view background image" shows this image:
[image: Sharing bar]

I *really* don't think this is what was intended when the page was designed...

Comment: @animuson, it's not a dupe of the question but of an answer, which means it's not a dupe.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: The question doesn't matter. Duplicate means there's an *answer to the question* there, and since this has already been brought up there (and will inevitably get solved there) (and [another question exactly like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186347) is already closed as a duplicate of it), it makes perfect sense to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: This should be fixed now, build just went out...can you confirm please?

Comment: @NickCraver It's fixed now.  Thanks!

Comment: @animuson, no that's not what it means.  It means the question is an exact duplicate.  It makes no sense to close it if it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug in it right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186346/13295) that affects Firefox users.